# ggrepel: using position_dodge in combination with geom_label_repel

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I'm trying to label the outliers in a `geom_boxplot` using `ggrepel::geom_label_repel`. It works nicely when there's only one grouping variable, but when I try it for multiple grouping variables I run into a problem. The position argument in ggrepel doesn't seem to work very consistently for some reason, see this example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

set.seed(1337)

df <- tibble(x = rnorm(500),
             g1 = factor(sample(c('A','B'), 500, replace = TRUE)),
             g2 = factor(sample(c('A','B'), 500, replace = TRUE)),
             rownames = 1:500)

is_outlier <- function(x) {
    return(x < quantile(x, 0.25) - 1.5 * IQR(x) | x > quantile(x, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(x))
}

df_outliers <- df %>% group_by(g1, g2) %>% mutate(outlier=is_outlier(x))

ggplot(df_outliers, aes(x=g1, y=x, fill=g2)) + 
    geom_boxplot(width=0.3, position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
    ggrepel::geom_label_repel(data=. %>% filter(outlier), 
                              aes(label=rownames), position = position_dodge(0.8))
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Is there a way to make the labels point to the accompanying dots using ggrepel?

Comment: I think at least part of the problem has to do with having no B (g1) A (g2) outliers.  You can get the dodging by adding that combination in, `. %>% filter(outlier) %>% group_by(g1) %>% complete(g2)`.  However, this doesn't fix the problem of how the lines are drawn with ggrepel.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
ggplot(df_outliers, 
       aes(x=g1, y=x, fill=g2, label=rownames)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.3, position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
  geom_label_repel(data = . %>%
                     filter(outlier) %>%
                     group_by(g1) %>%
                     complete(g2, fill = list(x = 0, rownames = "")),
                   position = position_dodge(0.5),
                   box.padding = 1,
                   min.segment.length = 0,
                   show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image: result]

Explanations:

1. The data source for `geom_label_repel()` follows aosmith's suggestion to add the B-A combination, filling `0` for x (any number would do, as long as it's not the default NA) and `""` for rowname (ggrepel won't plot empty labels, but *will* take them into account when dodging).
2. `box.padding` is set to 1 (increased from the default 0.25) to push the labels further away, so that the line segments are more visible.
3. `min.segment.length` is set to 0 (decreased from the default 0.5) to force line segments to be plotted, no matter how short they are.

(`show.legend = FALSE` is optional. I just don't like seeing "a" letter show up in the legend.)